# JavaScript: How to implement Binary Search Tree

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am implementing Binary Search Trees in JavaScript, but while writing the insert function, some error is occuring (most probably in the RECURSION).

Here is my code:

```js
class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.root = null;
  }
  insert(elem) {
    if (!this.root) {
      //If root is null then this is the root.
      this.root = new BSTNode(elem);
    } else {
      let newNode = new BSTNode(elem);
      let myRoot = this.getParent(this.root, elem)
      console.log(myRoot);

      if (myRoot[1] == 'left') myRoot[0].left = newNode;      //Error Line
      else myRoot[0].right = newNode;

      this.nodes.push(newNode);
      this.arr.push(elem);
    }
    this.length++
  }
  getParent(root, elem) { // the argument 'root' is ambiguous, but it is for the user

    if (elem < root.value) {
      if (root.left!==null) this.getParent(root.left, elem); 
      else return [root, 'left'];
    } else {
      if (root.right!==null) this.getParent(root.right, elem);
      else return [root, 'right']
    }
  }
}
class BSTNode {
  constructor(val) {
    this.value = val;
    this.left = null; //Left Node
    this.right = null; //Right Node
  }
}
```

There are two classes; namely `BinarySearchTree` and `BSTNode`.

The Error: 
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`

I am unable to find the mistake.

Note that other solutions to do the same thing is also welcome.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, It says that myRoot is not defined yet! are you sure that myRoot is defined correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should return the result of `this.getParent(root.left, elem);` and `this.getParent(root.right, elem);`

```
getParent(root, elem) { // the argument 'root' is ambiguous, but it is for the user

    if (elem < root.value) {

      if (root.left!==null) return this.getParent(root.left, elem); 
      else return [root, 'left'];
    } else {
      if (root.right!==null) return this.getParent(root.right, elem);
      else return [root, 'right']
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
getParent(root, elem) { // the argument 'root' is ambiguous, but it is for the user

    if (elem < root.value) {
      if (root.left!==null) return this.getParent(root.left, elem); 
      else return [root, 'left'];
    } else {
      if (root.right!==null) return this.getParent(root.right, elem);
      else return [root, 'right']
    }
  }
```

Without returing those values, it will do the work to find the node, but not return it. Most recurive functions return themselves, like: `function foo(){return foo()}`